# Complex generators in python

Tags: python, language-agnostic, generator

I have a long running task that must be guided by external code. But external code need some information about this task. This is my homebrew example:

```
def longtask(self):
    yield self.get_step_length(1)
    for x in self.perform_step(1):
        ...
        yield x.id

    yield self.get_step_length(2)
    for x in self.perform_step(2):
        ...
        yield x.value

...
# call site
generator = self.longtask()
step1len = generator.Next()
step1pb = ProgressBar('Step 1', step1len)
# pull only step 1 items
for index, id in itertools.izip(xrange(0, step1len), generator):
    step1pb.update(index)
    ...do something with id

step2len = generator.Next()
step2pb = ProgressBar('Step 2', step1len)
# pull only step 1 items
for index, value in itertools.izip(xrange(0, step1len), generator):
    step2pb.update(index)
    ... do something other with value
```

Is it right to use such a complex generator protocols in python, or I need to refactor  this code?

Comment: I don't think there's "right" or "wrong" here. To me, the example looks reasonable, if a bit complicated. It's hard to make suggestion without understanding the context, and the reasons why you chose this design in the first place.

Comment: Reason to use this design is that some information easy to retrieve from the running process than separate. For example, process can create database cursor that can be used to get some additional information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd refactor this to returning separate generators; you can use nested functions:

```
def longtask(self):
    def step_generator(step):
        for x in self.perform_step(step):
            ...
            yield x.id

    yield step_length_1, step_one_generator(1)
    yield step_length_2, step_one_generator(2)

generators = self.longtask()
for counter, (steplength, stepgen) in enumerate(generators):
    ProgressBar('Step %d' % counter, steplength)
    for index, value in enumerate(stepgen):
        # ....
```

Now you can also use the `enumerate()` function to add numbers to the items; that is much more readable than zipping together an `xrange()` and the generator.

Comment: The second loop in the generator yields `x.value` though, so I don’t think they are that similar.

Comment: @poke: You can use multiple nested functions too.